# Can git status be made to mention the stash?

Tags: git

I tend to forget that I had stashed some changes. I'd like to see stash mentioned in `git status` output, when the stash is not empty. Is there a way to get `git status` do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This is now a built-in option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#git-status---show-stash) in `git status`, so you can just do:

```
[status]
  showStash = true
```

If you're not comfortable editing your git config file, you can do

```
git config --global status.showStash true
```

Comment: I have immediately switched to this from my custom alias solution, it is far more efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see, there is no built-in option to do this, but there are a couple of ways of achieving the desired effect.

## git-prompt.sh

Source the [`git-prompt.sh` script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) as described in its documentation, and set the `GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE` variable, e.g. in `~/.bashrc`:

```
. ~/.bash/git-prompt.sh
GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE=1
PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\u@\h:\w" "\\\$ "'
```

Now your command prompt will show a dollar sign next to the branch name in the git prompt:

```
user@host:~/repo (master$)$
```

## git alias

You can make an alias for the desired functionality, although the alias cannot be `status`, it must be different from any built-in command:

```
git config --global alias.vstatus '!git status; git stash list'
```

This will set up a global alias `vstatus` (verbose status) that will simply run `git status` and `git stash list` back to back.

## shell alias

One can always make a shell alias to intercept git subcommand invocation, as git aliases for built-in commands are ignored. In `.bash_aliases`:

```
git () {
    command git "$@" || return # preserve $?
    [[ $1 = status ]] && command git stash list
}
```

This will simply always run `git stash list` after every git status. When the stash is empty, nothing will be output.